SQL select distinct with condition
I'm using oracle SQL.
ID | Name
----------
1     A
1     B
1     C 
2     D 
2     E
3     F

I want to get the ID column only if in 'Name' it doesn't have the letter A.
So for this example I'd want the results to be only: 2, 3.
How can I achieve that?
I tried:
select distinct ID
from table
where Name <> 'A'

But that obviously didn't work...
I also tried with listagg but I could find how to use condition within it.

For the future: 1. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS, because SQL dialects differ. 2. Never just say "it didn't work". Always tell us how this how this did not work (error message, too many rows, too few rows, wrong rows, ...) 3. Don't call a column ID when it is not the table's ID that uniquely identifies a row. While in your example it is obvious that the ID is not the ID, it may be very confusing with more complicated data and tasks.

Aggregate the rows with GROUP BY id. Then use a HAVING clause to only keep IDs that don't have an 'A' row:
select id
from table
group by id
having count(case when name = 'A' then 1 end) = 0;

Another simple option: Get all IDs minus 'A' IDs:
select id from table
minus
select id from table where name = 'A';

Well, there are many ways to approach this :-)
In a well-built database it is typical for a recurring column value to have a parent table (so as to avoid typos). In your example this could be something like:
CREATE TABLE groups 
(
  group_id INT,
  some_description_maybe VARCHAR(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE group_letters 
(
  group_id INT, 
  letter INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, letter),
  FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCING groups (group_id)
);

And the typical query would use a NOT IN or NOT EXISTS clause. Remember: SELECT DISTINCT is very often an indicator for an inappropriate query or an inappropriate database.
select *
from groups
where group_id not in (select group_id from group_letters where letter = 'A');


Thank you for accepting this answer. I added a comment on a properly built database and its typical solution, though. I hope you'll find this helpful.

select distinct id from table
minus
select id from table where name = 'A';  will be better

@tahzibi.jafar: Why? The DISTINCT would be superfluous, because MINUS (and EXCEPT in standard SQL) is a distinct operation by default.

Because of performance ( in minues par). If we have less records, MINUS takes less time.  I know that it add some overhead on first SELECT. overally in large data sets I think it is better

@tahzibi.jafar: You misundertand how SQL works. We tell the DBMS what to do, not how to do it. With either query the DBMS is free to first remove duplicates and then apply MINUS or vice versa. Don't try to force the DBMS some way. Let ist decide. Don't place unnecessary DISTINCT in your queries. This is more likely to keep the DBMS from finding the optimal execution plan than to find it(The same applies to IN clauses by the way.)

Theoretically, your argument is correct(and we desire it). But the suggestion is based on some of my  experinces (like SQL hints)

You can use a GROUP BY clause with HAVING to exclude those id`s having rows with name = 'A':
SELECT id 
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY id 
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN name = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY id; --skip the ORDER BY clause if sorting is not intended

See this sample fiddle with your data

You can use this query
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM your_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM your_table t_sub
    WHERE t_sub.ID = t.ID
      AND t_sub.Name = 'A'
);

And I also create this example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/nlzwmeRn

Use a subquery with NOT IN like,
select distinct ID
from table
where ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Name = 'A')


You can use this query for your question.
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'A' THEN 1 else 0 end) < 1

the SUM in HAVING part will be 0, when the ID contains  "A" in its name.

You can use below query. Just replace table name
select ID
from LOCALWORK
where Name <> 'A' and 
ID <>(Select ID from LOCALWORK where NAME='A')
group by ID



No. Once there is more than one 'A' row in the table, you will get ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row. You can use <> ALL instead, which is rather uncommon, or NOT IN, as has been suggested already. It is also uncommon to use GROUP BY without any aggregation function. We would rather use DISTINCT in that case to make our intention clear.

Got that! Thanks. In subquery we can use distinct to get rid of the ORA-01427

No, we can't. When there are two different IDs in the subquery, it will still be two different IDs after DISTINCT.

Rohan's existing answer achieves the intent of the SQL in this answer.
